# How to assign values from object by checking property name to array of objects via property name using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have array of objects, which has `"modulePermissions"` property name inside array of objects name `"tabList"`. I have one object as `"moduleName"`, which contains same value as `"modulePermissions"` name, to that boolean value has been assigned.
So now, to `"tabList"` we need to check for "modulePermissions" value, if "modulePermissions" value matches with `moduleName` property name, then the boolean value of moduleName` property to be assigned to "tabList" "enableTabs" as value.

Ts:

```
  moduleName = {
        Details: true,
        "Basic Info": true,
        "Captive Info": true,
        "Users": true,
        "Settings": true,
        "Restrictions": true,
        "Agents Group View": true,
        "W9": true,
        "EO": true,
        "License": true,
        "ACH": true,
        "Contacts": true,
        "Uploads": true,
        "Notes": true,
        "Tasks": true,
        "History": true,
        "Commissions": true
      }

tabList = [
    { name: 'Details', class: 'active', active: false, href: 'basic', tabEvent: '_detailsTab', id: 1, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions:'Details' },
    { name: 'W-9', class: '', active: false, href: 'w9', tabEvent: '_w9Tab', id: 2, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions:'W9' },
    { name: 'E&O', class: '', active: false, href: 'eo', tabEvent: '_eoTab', id: 3, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions:'EO'},
    { name: 'License', class: '', active: false, href: 'license', tabEvent: '_licenseTab', id: 4, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions:'License' },
    { name: 'ACH', class: '', active: false, href: 'ach', tabEvent: '_achTab', id: 5, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions:'ACH' },
    { name: 'Contacts', class: '', active: false, href: 'contacts', tabEvent: '_contactsTab', id: 6, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions:'Contacts' },
    { name: 'Uploads', class: '', active: false, href: 'uploads', tabEvent: '_uploadTab', id: 7, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions:'Uploads' },
    { name: 'Notes', class: '', active: false, href: 'notes', tabEvent: '_notesTab', id: 8, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions:'Notes' },
    { name: 'Tasks', class: '', active: false, href: 'tasks', tabEvent: '_taskTab', id: 9, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions:'Tasks' },
    { name: 'History', class: 'link-disabled', active: false, href: 'history', tabEvent: '_historyTab', id: 10, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions: 'History'},
    { name: 'Commissions', class: '', active: false, href: 'commission', tabEvent: '_commissionTab', id: 11, enableTabs: false,modulePermissions:'Commissions' }
  ]
```

i tried by using something like this :

```
getValue(){
   for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                this.tabList[i]['modulePermissions'] == userPermissions.moduleName.this.tabList[i]['modulePermissions'];
                this.tabList[i]['enableTabs'] = userPermissions.moduleName.this.tabList[i]['modulePermissions']
              }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do something like that :

```
for ( let i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++ ) {
    let module = tabList[i];
    if(moduleName[module.modulePermissions] !== undefined ){
        module.enableTabs = moduleName[module.modulePermissions];
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(moduleName[module.modulePermissions])` will not work, if the value in moduleName is set to false

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate tabList.

And `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check if the given property exists.

Something like this should work:

```
const getModifiedTabList = () => {
    return tabList.map((tabListEntry) => {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(moduleName, tabListEntry.modulePermissions)){
            const enableTabs = moduleName[tabListEntry.modulePermissions];
            return {...tabListEntry, ...{enableTabs}}
        }
        return tabListEntry
    })
}
```

PS: this example assumes that `moduleName` and `tabList`are available in the scope.